# Double many-to-many relationship

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, strongloop

In loopback I have defined two models with a double many-to-many relationship as follows:

**action.json:**

```
    {
      "name": "Action",
      "base": "PersistedModel",
      "idInjection": true,
      "options": {
        "validateUpsert": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
        }
      },
      "validations": [],
      "relations": {
        "benchmark": {
          "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
          "model": "Course",
          "foreignKey": "benchmark"
        },
        "main": {
          "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
          "model": "Course",
          "foreignKey": "main"
        }
      },
      "acls": [],
      "methods": {}
    }
```

**course.json:**

```
    {
      "name": "Course",
      "base": "TrashModel",
      "idInjection": true,
      "options": {
        "validateUpsert": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
        }
      },
      "validations": [],
      "relations": {
        "benchmark": {
          "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
          "model": "Action",
          "foreignKey": "benchmark"
        },
        "main": {
          "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
          "model": "Action",
          "foreignKey": "main"
        }
      },
      "acls": [],
      "methods": {}
    }
```

Now when I try to create a relation between an action model and a course model with the following PUT request:

http://localhost:3000/api/courses/57331a4eeff440cb02c886ae/benchmark/rel/5731d60da2c6d238e3c3d9b3

Then when I request the course model with the related action models included with the following GET request:

http://localhost:3000/api/courses/57331a4eeff440cb02c886ae?filter=%7B%22include%22%3A%5B%22benchmark%22%2C%22main%22%5D%7D

I get:

```
    {
      "name": "Introduction Lessons",
      "id": "57331a4eeff440cb02c886ae",
      "benchmark": [{
        "text": "text here",
        "id": "5731d60da2c6d238e3c3d9b3"
      }],
      "main": [{
        "text": "text here",
        "id": "5731d60da2c6d238e3c3d9b3"
      }]
    }
```

So apparently the action is now attached through both the benchmark as the main relation. How did this happen? Do I setup my models wrong?

Comment: how will your localhost will work as my localhost???!?!

Comment: @user2181397  it won't, I don't have an online demo.

Comment: Can you elaborate, what are you trying to achieve with this double relation? Why is one not enough? I'm also confused by your foreign keys. Can you explain, why did you set them the way, you did?

Comment: I had a typo in the foreignKeys of my action model, which I corrected in the edit.

Comment: A course has several benchmark actions and some main actions. All actions can be assigned as either a benchmark or a main action to a course. That's why I believe I need a double relation to the same model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, when you use hasAndBelongsToMany relashionship, loopback uses a through table which it manages automatically for you.

I believe by default it calls itself From_modelTo_model. In order to have two such relashion you need to tell loopback to manage it differently otherwise they use the same through table.

Try with **through** option such as

Action

```
"benchmark": {
  "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
  "model": "Course",
  "foreignKey": "benchmark",
  "through":"ActionCourseBenchmark"
},
"main": {
  "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
  "model": "Course",
  "foreignKey": "main",
  "through":"ActionCourseMain"
}
```

Course

```
"benchmark": {
  "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
  "model": "Action",
  "foreignKey": "benchmark",
  "through":"ActionCourseBenchmark"
},
"main": {
  "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
  "model": "Action",
  "foreignKey": "main",
  "through":"ActionCourseMain"
}
```

see [this github issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/732#issuecomment-61574999) for more details

Comment: Thanks for this answer! A few notes on it: you can use the same through model for both Action.benchmark as Course.benchmark (named it CourseActionBenchmark). Same for Action.main and Course.main (named it CourseActionMain). Also you need to create the through models manually.